# How are images downloaded on a incremental resolution basis?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Normally when you keep `<img/>` tag it shows from top to bottom while it is being downloaded from the web and looks very ugly but if you somebody's Facebook album and click on some photo you will see the whole photo is downloaded i.e the whole photo looks blurry/hazy and then as it downloaded from the web the picture goes clearer and clearer.

It looks so natural and as against the default behavior. How can this be done? I know it is Facebook and they can do anything they wish ;) but I need a brief overview of what they might have done to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the image that is in special form - saved as progressive.

About progressive JPEG:

A simple or "baseline" JPEG file is stored as one top-to-bottom scan of the
image.  Progressive JPEG divides the file into a series of scans.  The first
scan shows the image at the equivalent of a very low quality setting, and
therefore it takes very little space.  Following scans gradually improve the
quality.  Each scan adds to the data already provided, so that the total
storage requirement is roughly the same as for a baseline JPEG image of the
same quality as the final scan.  (Basically, progressive JPEG is just a
rearrangement of the same data into a more complicated order.)

[More information here.](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-11.html)

Comment: Caveat is that Internet Explorer doesn't render progressive JPEGs on load.  A long time ago you could use [`<img lowsrc=''>`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG_LOWSRC.html) with a black & white GIF.  These days you could probably do something with jQuery and a highly compressed thumbnail.

Comment: @Jacek_FH: But how do I convert a image into progressive jpg? Any links would be greatly useful. I use C# and Asp.Net

Answer (score 1):

Interlaced jpg's do that. As far as I know, it's not code, but it's how you edit/save the image in the image editor.

Comment: but I upload my image in simple form. Obviously they don't go on converting every single user's every single image into this specialized format so there has got to be code I think so.

Comment: @Anthony not only does facebook convert every photo you upload, they convert it into a few different qualities and resolutions for various places on their site. Furthermore they optimize it for web viewing, which yes means putting into this "special" format (which has been around for a VERY long time).

Comment: @jball: Because facebook has billions of users. They won't go in converting every user's photo manually into an image editor which Forrest says. I only said that "there has to be code".

Comment: @jball: I didn't understand what you are saying! Read Forrest's comment: "As far as I know, it's not code, but it's how you edit/save the image in the image editor." Read the line "it's not code". My understanding is if it's not code --> it's not automated and if it's not automated --> then it's manual.

Comment: @jball: There is a single line written in his "reply" and all I can find in that single or actually two lines is "it's not code". Nowehere it is mentioned whether he is talking about client code or server code. Unless I am god I can't make from this statement that he is talking about client side code. I can make more of an effort to understand him but only if he written enough in his reply. 1 Line is too less for me to guess/understand that he is talking about client code. He is talking about "edit/save the image in the image editor." and this completely implies that "he thinks" it is not code

Comment: @jball: Server side is not tagged but it is implied. That's the context you and Forrest needed to understand. I've tagged HTML, javascript and image because I gave an example of Facebook. But when I myself needed to implement such functionality it was understood that I am talking about server code. "Please give more of an effort to understand others.". You've given too much of an effort to understand and bring out hidden meaning (about code --> client code) from Forrest's 1 liner like the poet's do. But you and Forrest have failed to understand my basic context.